# Identifying address calculation insns in asm

Tags: c++, c, debugging, assembly, x86

I am looking at x86 asm and I wanna try to read it and identify a bug in my cpp code and OPTIMIZE. But the asm has a lot of overhead from address calculating instructions. And I can't seem to find a way to identify the ones that are calculating an address from the ones that are doing other tasks. for example an add could be used to both calculate a mem address to be used in later insn or to do a regular addition operation that is available in my code.

is there a way to do it easily, like do they used fixed registers for address calculation? or do I have to trace the code from beginning to end?

**EDIT:** it seems there is no clear way to identify them. But is it fair to assume that only mov, add, sub and lea are address calculating instructions? or does x86 have anything more complex?

thanks

Comment: Debugging C++ code by looking at the generated machine code is definitely the hardest possible way of getting bugs out of your code.  This is only a last resort approach, to be used when you have hard evidence that there's a bug in the code generator and/or optimizer.  Get the evidence first.

Comment: @Hans: yup I know that, I wanted to debug/optimize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. Most registers are general purpose, and used for all kinds of calculations. Some compilers are even smart enough to use address calculating instructions like LEA to compute other things.

You will probably have to find where a variable is loaded into a register, and follow it from there.

Comment: is it fair to assume that only mov, add, sub and lea are address calculating instructions? or does x86 have anything more complex?

Comment: @Syntax_Error, you can easily have multiplications when indexing arrays.

Comment: @Aprogrammer: so it fair it I assume mov add sub lea and mult? my main question is that can I limit the instructions that are used for address calculation? if yes what to? by limiting I mean 10insns tops

Comment: @Syntax_Error, I'm not sure where you put the limit between address calculation and data calculation.  Increment, decrement, shifts can be used for sure.  "or" and "and" could be used for alignment in some context (but I'm not sure there are compilers which does if the source code hasn't already them).  What's your goal?

Comment: No, you can't really know. I hinted at the fact that some instructions specifically designed for address calculations have been used for other things by clever compiler writers. So, sorry, but no.

Answer (score 2):

You can trace the code from end to beginning. For example, there are instructions that read or write registers to memory (e.g. `mov eax, [ebx]` using Microsoft syntax). When you see such an instruction, you can identify which register is used as an address (`ebx` in my example), then go back in the code and see how the register is calculated.

Beware of the "jump" instructions - if your code has much conditional execution, it might be hard to "go back in code", and it might be easier to just "trace the code from beginning to end".